# Differential equation A Level Year 2 Pure OCR book Chapter 13 Exercise 13C Question 7 check.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Newton's Law of cooling states that the rate of change of temperature of a body is proportional to the difference in temperature between the body and its surroundings.

A bottle of milk has temperature of $\ 5\ ^\circ$C when it is initially taken out of the fridge. It is placed on the table in the kitchen, where the room temperature is $\ 19\ ^\circ$C. Initially, the milk is warming up at a rate of $\ 5.7\ ^\circ$C per minute.

**a** Show that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}= 0.3(19-\theta),\ $ where $\theta\ ^\circ$C is the temperature of the milk and $\ t\ $ is the time, in minutes, since the milk was taken out the fridge.

**b** Solve the differential equation and, hence, find how long it takes, to the nearest minute, for the temperature of the milk to reach the kitchen temperature, correct to the nearest degree.

No answer is given in the back of the book for question **a** because it is a proof question. The answer given in the back of the book for **b** is:

**b** $\theta=19-14e^{-0.3t}; 11$ minutes.

My attempt:

**a** $\frac{d\theta}{dt}\ $ is the rate of change of the temperature of the milk. Therefore, $\frac{d\theta}{dt}= k(19-\theta).\ $ At $\ t=0,\ \frac{d\theta}{dt}\ = 5.7\ $ and $\ \theta=5.\ $ Therefore, $\ 5.7 = 14k \implies k = \frac{5.7}{14} = 0.407\ldots \neq 0.3$

Edit: I figured out my error for **b**, and in fact get the same answer as the back of the book, on the basis that $\theta=19-14e^{-0.3t}.$

So have I made a mistake in part **a**, or is the book wrong?

Comment: The book's answer is exactly equal to $\frac{5.7}{19}$ so I think they used 19 instead of 14. Did they mistake theta for t?

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So the book is wrong then?

Comment: It's not uncommon for the edexcel one

Comment: This is OCR, which I have found has a lot of mistakes in the answers at the back of the book, even compared to Edexcel...